# При конвертации из xml в json парсятся теги

Tags: php, xml

Делаю запрос к API, в ответ получаю xml-файл, кодирую его в json, декодирую в массив:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Но есть один нюанс. В одном из тегов xml есть следующий текст:

```
<conditions>
<ul><li>Цены на авиабилеты указаны с учетом топливных, аэропортовых и государственных сборов.</li><li>Количество авиабилетов на каждом рейсе по данному тарифу ограничено.</li><li>Курс расчета и цена в рублях могут меняться без предварительного уведомления.</li></ul>
</conditions>
```

В итоге, если я декодирую такую строку в массив и пытаюсь вывести через var_dump, то в вывод попадают и теги `<ul><li>`. Это нормально, если они будут храниться в качестве значения в массиве, или их лучше убирать(если да, то как)?

Comment: `то в вывод попадают и теги <ul><li>`. Тэги попадают как ключи массива, что ожидаемо.

Comment: может вам поможет https://lostechies.com/seanbiefeld/2011/10/21/simple-xml-to-json-with-php/