# Конвертация из xml в массив

Tags: php, xml

Пробовал конвертировать из xml в массив путём кодирования xml в json и затем обратно декодировать уже в массив, но в такой конструкции парс происходит с ошибками и возвращает побитый массив. Какие есть способы напрямую конвертировать xml в многомерный массив?

Comment: Через json у меня лично нормально отрабатывало, но большие YML не вариант таким способом конвертировать. Если приходит битый массив, значит, не валидный XML

Comment: @ilyaplot прошёлся валидатором по своему xml и он валиден. Вот XML - http://pastebin.com/mK65vpRn При конвертации его в json, а затем в массив появляются какие-то странные ключи в массиве с символом @ вначале. А ключи offer заменяются на ключи route. В итоге массив битый.

Comment: Точно не понмю, но @ перед ключом массива - это обозначение параметра

Comment: @ilyaplot в любом случае, у меня должно быть 30-40 offer, а не 1 offer и 30-40 вложенных route.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При конвертации из xml в json парсятся теги](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581767/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-xml-%d0%b2-json-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот такой способ с рекурсией

```php
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('xml.xml'), "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);


$array = array_map('normalizeArray', $array);

function normalizeArray($value)
{
    if (is_array($value)) {
        if (!empty($value['@attributes'])) {
            $attributes = $value['@attributes'];
            unset($value['@attributes']);
            $value = array_merge($value, $attributes);
        }

        $value = array_map('normalizeArray', $value);
    }

    return $value;
}

print_r($array);
```

Но все-таки я советую смотреть в сторону http://php.net/manual/ru/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php

Comment: Хм, у xml_parse_into_struct() очень странный вывод. Кажется, эта функция не умеет делать многомерные массивы.

Comment: Да, приходится рекурсивно с ней работать, учитывая уровень вложенности. Но она работает с огромными xml файлами в несколько гигабайт.

Comment: Есть какое-то готовое решение, чтобы не изобретать велосипед? Вот [это](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6533980/4704823), например, мне не помогло.

Comment: Возможно, но я не нашел в свое время.